# Why is my IC giving abnormally small voltage outputs?

Tags: voltage, integrated-circuit

I just got some new battery holders, with 4.5V and 6V respectively. I hooked up the 4.5V holder to a SR latch IC, and while it did hold a state, the LED was abnormally dim, despite having no resistors in between the output pin and LED. The schematic for my design is below:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fZcldb.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Half the time I couldn't see it at all, even when I set the latch. I tried another LED, and the same thing happened. I tried the 6V power source, and the LED didn't get any brighter. Can anyone explain what's wrong?

Comment: Which SR latch IC? What is the exact part number? How did you connect the LED to it? Did you use a current-limiting resistor? A schematic would have made all this clear from the start.

Comment: 74ls279 SR NAND latch

Comment: We can't troubleshoot blind. Give us a schematic and part numbers for all major components (latch, LED, and anything else major) and a link to the datasheet. This website has as schematic editor and you can edit all additional information into your original post.

Comment: 'Abnormally dim' compared to what? What color is the LED?

Comment: I used red, yellow, and blue silicone LEDs from Sparkfun Electronics. I could see only the red.

Comment: You've added the schematic (that's good) but you omitted the part number of the SR latch. Hit the edit link again ...

Comment: Might want to add pulldown resistors to your inputs. Are you assuming that when the pushbuttons are open that the SR latch will interpret that as a LO in the absence of a HI? Don't. What reason does it have to interpret a floating input as a LO?

Comment: A resistor needs to be added in series with the LED to limit to a safe level the current that (a) is sourced by the SR latch's output, and (b) is flowing through the LED. Without the current-limiting resistor you'll almost certainly damage or destroy the SR latch, the LED, or both.

Comment: @JimFischer "*Without the current-limiting resistor you'll almost certainly damage or destroy the SR latch*" At least, when it's working properly ;)

Comment: Silicon and silicone are two different things, @TrevorMershon

Comment: The high side of an LS device has a series resistance of about 120 ohms. Making things worse, its Voh is limited to 3.4V even if there is no load due to the Vce drop of the high-side driver. Low side is much better (16mA drive). The datasheet has more details.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Three problems:

- The inputs of an 'LS type device are *internally pulled high* (not a problem really, but an observation)
- the 'S-' and 'R-' input pins are *active low* (the switches won't do anything)
- The 'LS output high drive is *weak* (this is why the LED is dim)

How to fix it... make the S and R switches tie to ground instead of +4.5V. Use the Q- to drive the LED in sink configuration, and add a load resistor (about 330 ohms is good.)

Like this:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fYbHHSm.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Answer (score 0):

1. This ic is sourcing very little current when output is high. Only 0.4 mA  which explains why the light out of your led is barely noticeable.
   You can add a 10K pull up resistor (a resistor connected between 5V and the output pin. But I'm not 100% sure, whether this antiquated ic (1983) is designed for this. I just guess it is.

   2.
   But when the output is low, it's sinking 8 mA which would be enough to lit the led when it's off, and you put the led in the direction of the output pin, cathode connected to the output, with a 10K resistor to avoid exceeding 8mA and 5V at the anode.
   But this will show the indicator light only when it's off.

   3.
   I suggest looking at more modern ic's like the generic 4043 (several producers make them). It outputs from 2.4 to 4 mA. Just enough.

   4.Either you chose the old one or a new one, may I suggest to drive your led with a mosfet. So that in either case, it will draw very little current and enough current will remain for other operations. Often a small indicator led draws too much current to leave enough voltage for other inputs.